# how to change opencv configrations in cmake to support qt

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

I'm new to opencv. I installed it on my computer using `cmake` following the tutorial in their [website](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

```
mkdir Desctop/opencv
cd Desctop/opencv
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
sudo make install
```

And to [compile with opencv using cmake](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage), I add the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `cpp` file directory then execute

```
cd <cpp file directory>
cmake .
make
```

---

But now I know more about `opencv`. I know that I can make `GUI` windows with it; I can make buttons, scroll bars and many other `UI` controls.

But I can't use the `GUI` tools unless I integrated `cmake` with `QT`.I'm not sure how should it be, but I thing it would be something like

```
cmake -D WITH_QT=ON ..
```

[Reference](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)

But the problem is that I've already installed `opencv` and I don't know how can I change it's configurations to use `QT`.

I tried to install `cmake-gui` to change the `opencv` installation configurations but I didn't find anything for `opencv` in the program.

## My questions

- Do I need to re-install `opencv` or it's possible to change the settings or changing the content of `CMakeLists.txt` file?
- How can I change the configurations of the current `opencv` installation so it support `QT`?
- would I need to change the `CMakeLists.txt` file after changing `opencv`'s configurations?

Comment: can you use a CMake gui?

Comment: @Micka I installed opencv using terminal. But when I installed `cmake-gui` after that, I couldn't find any "project" for opencv. I know that I can reinstall opencv again using `cmake-gui`, but I want to know of I can change the configurations of the current installation instead of reinstalling opencv again.

Comment: just open the cmake file with the cmake gui (or choose the source folder)